# Unable to call function from onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a render within a component that looks like this:

```
  render() {
    if (!this.props.authorities) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

        return (
          <div>
            <Col xsOffset={0.5} md={2}>
              <ButtonGroup Col xsOffset={1} md={4} justified centered>
                <DropdownButton title="Authority" id="bg-justified-dropdown">
                  {this.props.authorities.map(this.renderAuthority)}
                </DropdownButton>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </Col>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

It renders a list of dropdown items using the renderAuthority function, which looks like this:

```
  renderAuthority(authorityData) {
    return (
      <MenuItem onClick={this.clickAuthority(authorityData.LocalAuthorityId)} key={authorityData.LocalAuthorityId} eventKey={authorityData.LocalAuthorityId}>{authorityData.Name}</MenuItem>
    )
  }
```

The onClick within there calls a function called clickAuthority, which looks like this:

```
clickAuthority(data) {
    this.props.fetchRatings(data)
  }
```

My constructor also looks like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickAuthority = this.clickAuthority.bind(this);
  }
```

However, I get an error with the following:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'clickAuthority' of undefined
```

This references the MenuItem onClick. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I might fix it?

Comment: Why no try {this.props.authorities.map(this.renderAuthority.bind(this)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `.map()` function bind the callback with global environnement object. So binds your `this.renderAuthority` function with `this` in your constructor too.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.renderAuthority = this.renderAuthority.bind(this);
  this.clickAuthority = this.clickAuthority.bind(this);
}
```

Secondly, when you are writing that:

```
onClick={this.clickAuthority(authorityData.LocalAuthorityId)}
```

You are instantly calling the function and giving its return to the `onClick` property. You have to make this:

```
onClick={() => this.clickAuthority(authorityData.LocalAuthorityId)}
```